# How do I return two functions in a function that renders as two components in react instead of the second function overwriting the first

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using a conditional rendering to render different elements in my react header based on url or if a user is logged in. In my default return I want to render two buttons side by side instead only the second button appears. How do I fix this?

```
const NavHeader = () => {
    const { location } = useSelector(state => state.router);
    const { authenticated } = useSelector(state => state.signIn);

    const menuItem = (linkPath, text, type) => (
        <Item className="header-item">
            <Button type="primary" ghost={type}>
                <Link to={linkPath}>
                    {text}
                </Link>
            </Button>
        </Item>
    );

    const renderMenuItem = ({ pathname }) => {
        if (pathname === '/signup') {
            return menuItem('/signin', SIGNIN, false);
        }
        if (pathname === '/signin') {
            return menuItem('/signup', SIGNUP, true);
        }
        if (authenticated) {
            return menuItem('/dashboard', GO_TO_DASHBOARD, false);
        }
        return (
            menuItem('/signin', SIGNIN, false)
            && menuItem('/signup', SIGNUP, true)
        );
    };

    return (
        <Header>
            <Link to="/" className="left-menu">
                <img src={Logo} height="60px" alt="NeoNatar Logo" />
            </Link>
            <Menu className="right-nav" mode="horizontal">
                {renderMenuItem(location)}
            </Menu>
        </Header>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an array or a fragment containing both.

Array:

```
return [
    menuItem('/signin', SIGNIN, false),
    menuItem('/signup', SIGNUP, true)
];
```

Fragment:

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
        {menuItem('/signin', SIGNIN, false)}
        {menuItem('/signup', SIGNUP, true)}
    </React.Fragment>
);
```

Another way to use fragment in modern versions of Babel:

```
return (
    <>
        {menuItem('/signin', SIGNIN, false)}
        {menuItem('/signup', SIGNUP, true)}
    </>
);
```

---

What you had didn't work because the result of the `&&` operator is the value of just **one** of its operands. It evaluates its left-hand operand and, if that value is falsy, takes that value as its result; otherwise, it evaluates its right-hand operand and takes that value as its result. In your case, since `menuItem` returns an object, it's truthy, so the second `menuItem` call was done and its result was the result of the `&&` expression.

Comment: I used the array, it's cleaner. Thank you.

Comment: @Ada - I think so too, it's not clear to me why I put it last. :-) Glad that helped!